# Как вывести слова из файла начинающиеся с гласной буквы?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, файлы, потоки-данных

У меня есть метод. Вроде должен работать, но не работает. Метод принимает путь к файлу и слова, которые начинаются с гласной буквы, добавляет в список. Но по итогу у меня выводит просто `[]`.

```
public static List<String> getTextListFromFileByFirstSymbol(String file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                .filter(i -> i.matches("[AaEeUuIiOoYy]"))
                .forEach(list::add);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Содержимое моего файла

```
Apple Dog Apple
Dog Orange Dog
```

Ожидаемый вывод

```
[Apple, Apple, Orange]
```

Реальный вывод

```
[]
```

Comment: Пробовали тестировать? Что выводится в консоль если в самом начале цикла while вывести line?

Comment: @Zhenyria да, выводит в две строки ``Apple Dog Apple \n Dog Orange Dog``. Так что тут все нормально. Cплитит тоже правильно, но вот на моменте проверки что то не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет у вас проблем с регулярным выражением, просто вы должны помнить, что `.matches()` требует совпадения целой строки.

Для устранения проблемы всего-навсего проверяйте *первый символ* вашей строки на совпадение уже имеющегося шаблона:

```java
Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
   .filter(i -> i.substring(0,1).matches("[AaEeUuIiOoYy]"))
   .forEach(list::add);
```

Первый символ здесь получается с помощью `i.substring(0,1)`.

Да, можно сократить длину выражения с помощью модификатора `(?i)`, `"(?i)[aeuioy]"`.

См. [пример работы кода на Java](https://ideone.com/cHLUms):

```
String text = "Apple Dog Apple\nDog Orange Dog";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line: text.split("\n")) {
    Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
           .filter(i -> i.substring(0,1).matches("[AaEeUuIiOoYy]"))
           .forEach(list::add);
}
System.out.println(list);
// => [Apple, Apple, Orange]
```

Хотя `^[AaEeUuIiOoYy].*` в данной ситуации является решением, помните, что в общем случае, данное выражение может не сработать, так как `.` не находит символов перевода строки. Можно в таких случаях использовать `(?s)^[AaEeUuIiOoYy].*`, где `(?s)` — это "встроенный" модификатор `Pattern.DOTALL`, который позволяет `.` находить все символы включая символы перевода строки.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший развернутый ответ